# getRecentPrioritizationFees is not a function ; solana web3js

Tags: error, priority-fees

I am not able to figure out what is going on.. I am using @solana/web3.js version 1.89.1 (latest) . What am I doing wrong here? Based on [this doc](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#getRecentPrioritizationFees), the usage seems to be fine

Anyone?

Here is my code example:

```
import { Connection } from '@solana/web3.js';

export class SolanaPlatform<N extends Network> extends PlatformContext<
  N,
  SolanaPlatformType
> {
  static _platform = _platform;

  constructor(network: N, config?: ChainsConfig<N, SolanaPlatformType>) {
    super(
      network,
      config ?? networkPlatformConfigs(network, SolanaPlatform._platform),
    );
  }

  static async getPrFees(rpc: Connection): Promise<{ prioritizationFee: number; slot: number }[]> {
    try {
      const obj: { prioritizationFee: number; slot: number }[] = await rpc.getRecentPrioritizationFees();
      console.log("Prioritization Fees", obj);
      return obj;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching prioritization fees:", error);
      throw error;
    }
  }
}

// Example usage
try {
  let rpf = await SolanaPlatform.getPrFees(this._rpc);
  console.log("rpf", rpf);
} catch (error) {
  // Handle error
  console.error("Error:", error);
}
```

I am getting this error.. it works fine when i do **getBlockheight** for example.

```
TypeError: rpc.getRecentPrioritizationFees is not a function
```

Comment: Strange, that should definitely work! Here's a simple example, does this work if you plug the code that creates your `this._rpc` in as `connection`? https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-5ugjpk?file=index.mjs

Comment: Perhaps you're using a very outdated version of web3.js, make sure to double check this too.

Comment: I am at version 1.89.1 for web3.js.. I am able to get the priority fees in a separate script.. Idk why this one isn't working.. pretty weird.. let me  research more.. it seems to be an issue with different thing.. not web3.js itself..

Answer (score 0):

So.. I was able to pull get priorityFees when I code it outside of the Wormhole Project.. Looked at it more closely. Wormhole is indeed using the outdated web3.js for the connect sdk.. A PR was raised by WH team to bump web3.js version in upcoming major release -->https://github.com/wormhole-foundation/connect-sdk/pull/275/files

https://github.com/wormhole-foundation/connect-sdk/blob/main/platforms/solana/package.json#L54